# spark data frame operation row and column level useing scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Original Data frame
      0.2       0.3

```
+------+------------- -+
|  name| country |
+------+---------------+
|Raju  |UAS         |
|Ram  |Pak.         |
|null    |China      |
|null    |null          |
+------+--------------+

  I Need  this 
+------+--------------+
|Nwet|wet Con |
+------+--------------+
|0.2   | 0.3           |
|0.2   | 0.3           |
|0.0   | 0.3.          |
|0.0   | 0.0           |
+------+--------------+
```

i want to create one Udf .  for Both the column
which will  apply to Name Column it check the if it not null then it return 0.2  return 0.0 .
and same Udf apply to country column check if it null return 0.0 . not null then it return 0.3

Comment: You want to return only one value or two values based on two columns ?

Comment: See my reply to your duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887546/udf-take-two-parameter-spark-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Using StringUtils of apache:

```
val transcodificationName: UserDefinedFunction =
    udf { (name: String) => {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(name)) 0.0
        else 0.2
        }
    }
val transcodificationCountry: UserDefinedFunction =
    udf { (country: String) => {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(country)) 0.0
        else 0.3
        }
    }

dataframe
    .withColumn("Nwet", transcodificationName(col("name"))).cast(DoubleType)
    .withColumn("wetCon", transcodificationCountry(col("country"))).cast(DoubleType)
    .select("Nwet", "wetcon")
```

edit:

```
val transcodificationColumns: UserDefinedFunction =
        udf { (input: String, columnName:String) => {
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(country)) 0.0
                else if(columnName.equals("name")) 0.2
                else if(columnName.equals("country") 0.3
                else 0.0
            }
        }


    dataframe
        .withColumn("Nwet", transcodificationColumns(col("name"), "name")).cast(DoubleType)
        .withColumn("wetCon", transcodificationColumns(col("country")), "country").cast(DoubleType)
        .select("Nwet", "wetcon")
```

Comment: I need one udf for two columns

Comment: it's impossible becuse one udf can have only one column in output. Another way is to return an arrayType, but is not your case because it will be always 1 column

Comment: mybe you want use one udf for each column? In this case i edited post