# UDF take two parameter spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Original Data frame

```
+------+--------+
|  name| country|
+------+--------+
|Raju  |UAS     |
|Ram   |Pak     |
|null  |China   |
|null  |null    |
+------+--------+

  I Need  this 
+------+--------+
|Namwet|wet Con |
+------+--------+
|0.2   | 0.3    |
|0.2   | 0.3    |
|0.0   | 0.3    |
|0.0   | 0.0    |
+------+--------+
```

i want to create one Udf for both columns
which will  apply to Name Column it check them, if it not null then it return should 0.2, otherwise should return 0.0 .
and same Udf apply to country column check if it null return 0.0 . not null then it return 0.3

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a udf.

You can do something like this

```
df
  .select(
    when($"name".isNotNull, 0.2).otherwise(0.0).as("Namewet"),
    when($"country".isNotNull, 0.3).otherwise(0.0).as("wet Con"),
    // Select more columns as required)
```

Comment: If i have more than 15 column are there .then

Comment: See edited code above